# Android App: The app crashes when i take NO photo with the Camera

Tags: android

i have following Problem with my app:
When i take a foto with the camera and  press the SEND TO EMAIL Button it all works fine, the picture is saved on the phone and it is loading up to my email Intent. BUT when i take NO image and i press the SEND TO EMAIL Button the app crashes ! Could someone Help me out ??

The Email Intent Code:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(foto));
```

The Camera Intent Code:

```
FotoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.FotoButton);
    FotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startCamera();
        }
    });
}

private void startCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    foto = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Fehlerbild.jpg");
    Uri image = Uri.fromFile(foto);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image);
    startActivityForResult(intent,TAKE_FOTO);
```

The Crashed Code:

```
04-02 11:57:30.229 21042-21042/de.cmoreno.hcsedv_service E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.cmoreno.hcsedv_service, PID: 21042
java.lang.NullPointerException: file
   at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:448)
   at de.cmoreno.hcsedv_service.Main2Activity$1.onClick(Main2Activity.java:174)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5242)
   at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10573)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Show us your activityforresult.

Comment: Sorry i am new at android and i have no activityforResult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are not including any photo, `foto` is `null`:

```
foto = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Fehlerbild.jpg");
```

Try not to include this in that case.

Edit 1:

Based on comments:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(foto)); // this is causing problem.
```

change it to like this:

```
if(foto!=null){
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(foto));
}
```

Comment: Exception at : `Main2Activity.java:174`

Comment: could you pleaswe show me an example with my code ??

Comment: Exception at : Main2Activity.java:174 =    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(foto));

Comment: Here `foto` is null because you haven't sent any photo.

Comment: OK It Works thanks a lot !!

Comment: Hi @Chris, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. BTW there is no obligation to do this.